# Changing the CSS in code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, code-behind

in my aspx page I have this div..

`<div id="downloadableProducts" runat="server"><a href="#">Downloadedable Products</a></div>`

I am trying to change the css in the code behind like this..

`downloadableProducts.Style("display") = "none";`

but this does not work, I get an error and red underline under `downloadableProducts` in the code behind and it says 'The name 'downloadableProducts' does not exist in the current context
'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also for those who copy this code it won't work straigth out of the box it's missing braces around "display" it should look like this..
downloadableProducts.Style["display"] = "none"; as we are writing C# code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add `runat="server"` to the div and access it as a `HtmlControl` in your codebehind. For example:

```
HtmlControl div1 = (HtmlControl)Page.FindControl("downloadableProducts");
```